# Why does python fail on NoneType when "None" doesnt return in function?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to create a list of keys from the filteredKeys() function, but when I call the function I get a TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable.

'None' doesnt exist when I print the result of filteredKeys() but when I convert it to a list. What am i missing? It's driving me crazy!

```
        key_list = []
        for line in stdout.read().splitlines():
            input_line = line
            input_line = input_line.replace(b'[sudo] password for ufitadmin: ', b'')
            key_individual = str(input_line, 'utf-8')
            key_individual = key_individual.replace(
                'cat: /home/%s/.ssh/authorized_keys: No such file or directory' % user,
                'No key exists for this user.')
            key_list.append(key_individual)


        global keyDict
        keyDict = {}
        keyDict[host] = key_list
        filterString = "No key exists for this user."
        filteredKeylist = []

        def filteredKeys():
            for key,value in keyDict.items():
               for values in value:
                   if values == filterString:
                       return key



        filteredKeylist = list(filteredKeys())

        print(filteredKeylist)
```

Comment: Could `value` be None here: `for values in value:`?

Comment: It's certainly not clear that `filteredKeys` will always find a match; when it doesn't find a match and `return key`, then it's implicitly returning `None`.

Comment: Also, this is **way** more code than it needs to be. A good SO question will have a small, self-contained code sample (in this case, perhaps *only* including the `filteredKeys` function, with a `keyDict` and `filterString` for which the problem occurs hardcoded). See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `filteredKeys()` function is actually very likely to return `None` - when none of the values matches `filterString`.

Also, you state that you want to "create a list of keys from the filteredKeys() function", but since it returns a single value (either `None` or the first key having a value matching `filterString`), it just WontWork as you expect.

A better implementation would be to make it a generator:

```
def filteredKeys():
    for key,values in keyDict.items():
       if filterString in values:
           yield key

filteredKeylist = list(filteredKeys())
```

but that's still a uselessly complicated way to write:

```
 filteredKeylist = [key for key, values in keyDict.items() if filterString in values]
```

Also globally your code seems overly complicated and I can already spot an obvious bug with keyDict being overwritten on each iteration.

Comment: I updated my code to use your one liner, however it is still returning individual lists instead of one large list with all the values.

it returns:
    `[]
    [item 1]
    []
    [item 2]` all on individual lines.

Comment: It's not "returning" anything (from the code you posted), it's _printing_ individual lists. And that's what one would expect since you're doing this in a loop, recreating this list for each host (cf the code that's been edited out). This is actually a completely different issue (and certainly not the only one with your code, cf my note about `KeyDict` being overwritten in each iteration). I answered your question (with explanations and a working solution for the problem at hand) and even provided a couple more hints, but I'm not going to debug your whole code.

Comment: You're right, your solution answers my question. Thank you.